# single entity for different tables

Tags: entity-framework-4

I have same type of tables

ProductCodeTable, CountrycodeTable etc

All have key, value as their fields

When I use entity frame work, 
Can I have a single entity for all these tables such that I can formulate different queries to get data from different tables?

Comment: are you saying that each table is setup something like the following

| ID | KEY | VALUE | TIME

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can create a view with a Union of all tables like this:

```
create view AllKeyTables as 

SELECT 'Product' as table, Productkey as Key, nameProduct as name 
FROM ProductCodeTable
UNION
SELECT 'Country' as table, CountryISO as key, CountryName as name 
FROM CountrycodeTable
UNION
...
```

Then update EF model and check 'table' and 'key' fields as Entity Primary Key.

Next question you will do is: 'How can I make a relation between this Entity and existing Entities?' The answer is 'you can't because EF is not able to join Entities between other fields than primary key'. Then, before implement this solution, be sure that this is you are looking for.

Answer (score 1):

You can create a base class for all of them and create sub class for each entity

```
public abstract class LookUpEntity
{
    [Key]
    public int Key { get; set; }

    [Required]
    public string Value { get; set; }
}

[Table("ProductCodeTable")]
public class ProductCode : LookUpEntity
{

}
```

This way you can model the relationships also and later if you wanted to add specific properties to those look up entities with out affecting other entities.

Answer (score 0):

EF supports this only if you model it as inheritance (@Eranga showed it in code-first approach). You will have single base entity and derived entity for each table so you will not avoid having different type for each table. Otherwise the answer is no.

Inheritance will put additional requirements on data in your tables. For example Ids will have to be unique among all tables. So if `ProductTableCode` will have record with Id 1, `CountryCodeTable` (and any other code table) mustn't have record with Id 1.

Also inheritance in EF can produce nasty and very poorly performing queries.